# multiple components in the same viewports with new angular router.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view, components, router

I'm trying to add multiple components to the same viewport, if possible, with the new router and using angular 1.4. Here's my example

```js
 var module = angular.module("CougsApp", ["ngNewRouter", "CougsApp.nav", "CougsApp.headlines", "CougsApp.social", "CougsApp.relatedstories", "CougsApp.footer"]);
    module.controller("MainController", function ($scope, $router) {
        $scope.title = "This is demo of application";
        $router.config([
            {
                path: "/",
                component: {
                    navViewPort: "nav",
                    contentViewPort: "headlines",
                    contentViewPort: "social",
                    bottomContentViewPort: "relatedstories",
                    footerViewPort: "footer" 
                }
        } 

               ]);
    });
```

```html
<body ng-app='CougsApp' ng-controller="MainController">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default top-main-menu navbar-fixed-top" ng-viewport="navViewPort"></nav>
    <div class="container home-stream">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="headlines-stream col-md-9">
                <div ng-viewport="contentViewPort"></div>
                <div ng-viewport="bottomContentViewPort"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="social-stream feed col-md-3">
                <div ng-viewport="rightsideViewPort"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div> 


    <div class ="container-fluid footer footer_image" id="footer_image"  ng-viewport="footerViewPort">
        
    </div>
  
  </body>
```

Is this even possible with the new router in Angular? We want to be able to slip in new components without having to add more viewports into the index.html. Not a huge pain to do but I would think it's more efficient.